# Unable to view text in the viewpager kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-imageview, textview

I am suing viewpager for sliding images along with their text in android using kotlin. Despite having text in the layout and also adding the text to the view I am unable to view the text.

The layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="300dp"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/sliding_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="270dp"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sliding_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#200"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sliding_image"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

The code snippet of the Adapter:

```
class SliderAdapter:PagerAdapter{

var context:Context
private var images:Array<Int>
private var texts:Array<Int>
lateinit var inflater: LayoutInflater

constructor(context: Context,images:Array<Int>,texts:Array<Int>):super(){
    this.context=context
    this.images=images
    this.texts=texts
}

override fun isViewFromObject(view: View, `object`: Any): Boolean = view == `object` as RelativeLayout

override fun getCount(): Int = images.size

override fun instantiateItem(collection: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {
    var image:ImageView
    var text:TextView
    inflater=context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    var view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.splashscreenslider, collection,false)
    image = view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_image)
    image.setImageResource(images[position])
    text = view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_text)
    text?.text= texts[position].toString()
    println("${text?.text}")
    collection.addView(view)
    return view
}

override fun destroyItem(collection: ViewGroup, position: Int, `object`: Any) {
    collection.removeView(`object` as RelativeLayout)
}

}
```

By the way I'm not using fragments. I'm using only the views.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What color is the background? `#200` is a very, very dark red.

Comment: @MikeM. text is black. background is white. Anyways thank you I figured out, the text was behind the imageview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is modifying the layout file. This worked for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="300dp"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/sliding_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sliding_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:textColor="#200"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sliding_image"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

The code snippet in the Adapter is given below.

```
class SliderAdapter:PagerAdapter{

var context:Context
private var images:Array<Int>
private var texts:Array<Int>
private lateinit var inflater: LayoutInflater

constructor(context: Context,images:Array<Int>,texts:Array<Int>):super(){
    this.context=context
    this.images=images
    this.texts=texts
}

override fun isViewFromObject(view: View, `object`: Any): Boolean = view == `object` as RelativeLayout

override fun getCount(): Int = images.size

override fun instantiateItem(collection: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {
    var image:ImageView
    var textview:TextView
    inflater=context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    var view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.splashscreenslider, collection,false)
    image = view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_image)
    image.setImageResource(images[position])
    textview = view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_text)
    textview?.setText(texts[position])
    println("${textview?.text}")
    collection.addView(view)
    return view
}

override fun destroyItem(collection: ViewGroup, position: Int, `object`: Any) {
    collection.removeView(`object` as RelativeLayout)
}

}
```

Thank you Mike for responding.